# need advice on how to properly use a strtok()

Tags: c

I have been working on a problem in my c programming classes.After toiling for a few days I have decided to seek advice from veterans here.

strtok() using this function I am unable to get the required output which I have posted below .Kindly suggest what changes I can make.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main( )

{

int i,j,k;

char str[50] =":FIRSTNAME:Krishna::MIDDLENAME:Prasad::LASTNAME: Iyer::EMAIL:kpIyer@microsoft.com::CARNO:1221 YC 90PA:.";

char *p,*q,*r,*z;     //character array to store each substring name;


char seps[] =":";    //delimiter : or::

p=(char*)malloc(70); //allocating memory for substring arrays
q=(char*)malloc(70);
r=(char*)malloc(70);
z=(char*)malloc(70);

p= strtok(str,seps );//strtok for first string
q=strtok(NULL,seps );
r= strtok(NULL, seps );
z= strtok(NULL, seps );

puts(p);
puts(q);
puts(r);
puts(z);

sprintf(z,"%s %s %s",p ,q ,r);//appending all the strings into one single array.
//puts(z);


return 0;

}
}
```

The output I need is **"Krishna Prasad Iyer"** but unfortuntely I am getting

```
FIRSTNAME
krishna
MIDDLENAME
prasad
```

Kindly suggest what I can change..

Comment: `char str[50] =":FIRSTNAME:Krishna::MIDDLENAME:Prasad::LASTNAME: Iyer::EMAIL:kpIyer@microsoft.com::CARNO:1221 YC 90PA:.";` is already undefined. The string literal is significantly longer than the storage reserved for `str`.

Comment: Yes,I'm getting this error and I don't know what to do.I apologize I am new to programming

Comment: Please `free` the memory as It can cause memory leak and also  size of array `str`.

Comment: I have changed the str..but still I am getting the same error

Comment: The comment from @EOF is confirmed by MSVC compiler quite clearly: *test.c(11) : warning C4045: 'str' : array bounds overflow*. Please enable and deal with all warnings! The declaration should be `char str[] ="...";`

Comment: The line `sprintf(z,...` will fail because `z` is pointing (if it is not `NULL`) to a fragment on `str[]`.

Comment: @ameyCU the memory cannot be `free`ed because OP has overwritten the pointers returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane so in such case there is no need of it ? Am I getting right  now ?

Comment: I'm getting this error after using free "warning: attempt to free a non-heap object 'str' [-Wfree-nonheap-object]|"using code blocks IDE

Comment: @Michael yes please ignore my comment . Don't free memnory.

Comment: @Michael please don't tinker with the posted code's faults in response to comments, it makes them look stupid.

Comment: @Weather Vane , Sorry I'm new to this SOF etiquette s.

Comment: My advice: *don't use `strtok`*; use `snprintf`  not `sprintf`

Comment: @EOF Sure `char str[50] =":FIRSTNAME:...` is _undefined_ because it is too long?  Confident that this is _defined_ as in "An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal ... Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array." §6.7.9 14, but is certainly not what OP is hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I comment your program to show some of its errors.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    int i,j,k;
    // here the array is not big enough
    char str[50] =":FIRSTNAME:Krishna::MIDDLENAME:Prasad::LASTNAME: Iyer::EMAIL:kpIyer@microsoft.com::CARNO:1221 YC 90PA:.";
    char *p,*q,*r,*z;
    // here the delimiters are wrong, because of the space before "Iyer"
    char seps[] =":";

    // here you needlessly allocate memory
    p=(char*)malloc(70);
    q=(char*)malloc(70);
    r=(char*)malloc(70);
    z=(char*)malloc(70);

    // here you overwrite the pointers returned by malloc()
    // and you dont check their value for NULL
    p= strtok(str, seps );
    q= strtok(NULL, seps );
    r= strtok(NULL, seps );
    z= strtok(NULL, seps );

    puts(p);
    puts(q);
    puts(r);
    puts(z);

    // here you are overwriting a fragment of your input string
    // assuming z != NULL from malloc()
    sprintf(z,"%s %s %s",p ,q ,r);
    return 0;
}
```

Now here's an edit, commenting where it's different. Note that this wont work properly when you extract fields with a space in the data, such as the field `CARNO`. That's a drawback of the `strtok()` method: you can't have a space as a delimitor *and* as part of the data. You would have to remove `' '` from the `seps[]` and clean leading and trailing spaces off the substrings.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    // let the compiler determine the array size
    char str[] =":FIRSTNAME:Krishna::MIDDLENAME:Prasad::LASTNAME: Iyer::EMAIL:kpIyer@microsoft.com::CARNO:1221 YC 90PA:.";
    char *p,*q,*r,*z;
    char seps[] =" :";              // added 'space' to delimiters array

    z= strtok(str, seps );          // read first field identifier
    if (z == NULL)
        exit (1);
    if (strcmp(z, "FIRSTNAME"))     // check the field name
        exit (1);
    p= strtok(NULL, seps );         // read first data field
    if (p == NULL)
        exit (1);

    z= strtok(NULL, seps );         // read second field identifier
    if (z == NULL)
        exit (1);
    if (strcmp(z, "MIDDLENAME"))    // check the field name
        exit (1);
    q= strtok(NULL, seps );         // read second data field
    if (q == NULL)
        exit (1);

    z= strtok(NULL, seps );         // read third field identifier
    if (z == NULL)
        exit (1);
    if (strcmp(z, "LASTNAME"))      // check the field name
        exit (1);
    r= strtok(NULL, seps );         // read third data field
    if (r == NULL)
        exit (1);

    printf("%s %s %s\n", p ,q ,r);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Krishna Prasad Iyer
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your help, @Weather Vane I will reflect on your code for a time.

Comment: @Michael after reflecting and you think this is the right answer, please "accept" it.